# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{3} \right)\frac{1}{n^r}$ diverges for $0<r<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I would like to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{3} \right)\frac{1}{n^r}$ diverges when $0<r<1$. I'm having a hard time doing this though. It seems that p-series would obviously be related, but I can't make any comparison work.

Additionally, how could I show that the sum converges for $r=1$?

Comment: You might want to look up Dirichlet's test for convergence.

Comment: @wesley The series converges for $r>0$.

Comment: @MarkViola By Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Yes.  Or use summation by parts.